# Adding a basic banner to top of tumblr website

Tags: html, css, url, tumblr, banner

I just want to add a basic banner at the top of my tumblr website. The code (posted below) is just below the `<body>` part of the html, however I can't figure out why any img link that I put into the 'imgurlhere' section only shows up as a broken icon (see picture).

```
 <a href=“myurlhere”><center><img src=“imgurlhere” width=“500”></center></a>
```

[broken image icon that's showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLgR7.png)

My idea is to upload a short gif to tumblr, and then copy the code into the html so that it is placed at the top of my website as an advertisement. However, every url I put into the 'imgurlhere' section shows up as broken - regardless of advice I've found online stating that's all one needs to do.

- I'm making sure to include the correct link, such as .png etc
- And making sure to copy it straight from the 'copy image address'.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, try setting some height for the image like height:200px;

Comment: Hi Rishabh, good suggestion, however, just tried this and it still shows a broken image icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that setting width="500" in img tag was causing this issue.

-The best way would be to add a class and then set the width of the image.

```css
.image{
width:500px;

}
```

```html
<a href=“#”><center><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/302804/pexels-photo-302804.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="image"></center></a>
```

Try using your image there and let me know if it works or not.Thank You

Comment: Hi Rishabh, this is the one! I've got it working now. Thanks so much for your time and help!

Comment: I am very happy helping you :)